# Unable to store user's location in a variable

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook-graph-api

```
- (IBAction)getdirections:(id)sender {
    directionview=[[directionViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"directionViewController" bundle:nil];
    directionview.sourceplace=user.location;
    [self.view addSubview:directionview.view];
}
```

I want to store the user's locations in "sourceplace" which is a `NSString` type variable in another view controller named "`directionViewController`".
I am fetching data in variable "user" from  and i tried `NSLogging` user and i can see that it has the "location" key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .h :

```
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface yourController : UIViewController <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    NSString *str;
}
```

In your .m :

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

You can convert location to string from location like this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation *location = [locations lastObject];
    str=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@" latitude:%f longitude:%f", location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);    
}
```

after

if your directionview.sourceplace is a `NSString` too:

```
directionview.sourceplace = str;
```

Comment: you mean CLLocationManager in first line...right?
and i am getting an error saying "no known class method for selector 'location'"
sorry if i am doing a noob mistake,i am pretty new to ios development

Comment: i implemented ur procedure exactly same but i am getting an error saying "No visible @interface for CLLocation declares the selector lastObject"

Comment: yes i hav added
i had to add it in root viewcontroller's header file...right?

Comment: locations is an Array which contains the user's location coordinates. [locations lastObject] is only get the latest coordinate. I think you forgot to add 's' at the end of location. CLLocation *location , and [locations lastObject];  not location simple

Comment: You have to add CoreLocation framework at: go to your target, after go to Build Phases, then in Link Binary With Libraries click on '+' and search for CoreLocation, then add it !

Comment: i added CoreLocation.framework in my Frameworks folder but it changed nothing to my code  :(
are u on skype?then maybe u can help me by watching my screen once

Comment: its same as what was before adding that framework
No visible @interface for CLLocation declares the selector lastObject

If no skype then teamviewer? plz

Comment: 288 166 990                           
1q84nf